# C# Am i using lock correctly?

Tags: c#, multithreading, logging, locking

I'm currently trying to write a thread-safe logger class. I'm not very familiar with correct design and best practices in this area. Is there a flaw in my code?

```
public class WriteStuff
{
    private readonly StreamWriter m_Writer;
    private readonly object m_WriteLock = new object ();

    public WriteStuff(String path)
    {
        m_Writer = File.CreateText (path);

        m_Writer.WriteLine ("x");
        m_Writer.Flush ();
    }

    public void ListenTo(Foo foo)
    {
        foo.SomeEvent += new EventHandler<SomeArgs> (Foo_Update);
    }

    private void Foo_Update(object sender, SomeArgs args)
    {
        lock (m_WriteLock) {
            m_Writer.WriteLine (args);
            m_Writer.Flush ();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you've posted looks fine from a multi-threading perpective. Although I could be wrong, it would appear that any other code that does some multi-threading (even using the foo object) should be safe. Certainly, I can't see any [deadlocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163618.aspx) in the that section of code.

A few things worth noting anyway (apart from being very careful with deadlocks and testing rigourously to insure they won't occur):

- It's best to put a lock around the code within the constructor, as I believe it's *possible* in certain circumstances that methods can be called before the constructor block has finished executing. (Someone please correct me if I'm wrong on this one.)
- The `StreamWriter` object in this case is private, which is good. If it were protected or internal you would certainly have to be cautious about how other code utilised the object (in fact I think it would be best to almost *always* declare such objects as private).
- You've done locking the right way! It's always safest to lock on a separate private instance object because you *know* that object can't be locked by any other code than your own (which isn't the case if you lock `this` or the `StreamWriter` object itself).

Still, I may be missing something, and there is a small possibility that some other code not shown above might cause problems, but as far as I can see it that code isn't flawed except for a *possible* missing lock around the constructor code. You're more likely to have to watch out for deadlock situations when you start doing more complex multi-threading, especially across classes/instances.

Anyway, hope that helps.

Comment: Noldorin, you posted it 8 years ago so you probably found it out anyway, but yes, while specification states that public address is returned from IL newobj only AFTER the new object is constructed, JIT compiler can in some situations re-order instructions, so lock in constructor is a nice precaution measure.

Answer (score 9):

Well, that looks OK to me; I'd probably implement `IDisposable` as a means to `Close()` the file, but...

Of course, you could also use any of the (many) pre-canned logging frameworks.

---

Update:

One thought: you might want to consider what happens if the file already exists; you don't want to stomp on your logs...

Comment: WriteStuff is a constructor, why'd you need to synchronize it?

Comment: @arul - I went mad for a minute; edited to add, and edited to remove - a comment about WriteStuff. Insanity over.

Answer (score 1):

The event handler is on the same thread as the event generator which means your app could end up being held up by your log file write.

```
private void Foo_Update(object sender, SomeArgs args)        { 
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(WriteAsync, args);
}

private void WriteAsync(object state) {  
    SomeArgs args = (SomeArgs)state;    
    lock (m_WriteLock) {                        
       m_Writer.WriteLine (args);                        
       m_Writer.Flush ();                
   }        
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the downvote but: 1) You've just discarded the sender argument. 2) Working around (non-existant) 'thread' issue by spawning another thread/using the thread pool makes no sense. Maybe if you could elaborate just a little bit ...

Comment: 1: Is irrelevant as OP doesn't make use of it and anyway could easily pass across if needed. 2: Unless every Foo object in the application is on its own thread or fires SomeEvent on a new thread then the logging will become a bottleneck. Strange to downvote because you don't understand something...

Comment: 1) I wouldn't suppose OP's class is going to be called 'WriteStuff' with a 'Foo_Update' event handler either. 2) I believe that OP's looking for a thread-safe logger rather than an asynchronous logger. Apples and oranges.

Comment: 1: Huh? Those are simply the example methods the OP used. 2: The OP seems to be looking for advice writing his logger to me. If he hasn't found out already that logging to a file in a sync fashion blocks his app down he soon will.

Comment: Actually, I was mainly wondering about thread safety and design mistakes. Thank you for pointing out the possible problem of blocking when logging, though.