# lock() inside instance constructor

Tags: c#, multithreading, constructor

I found in some code lock statement inside instance constructor. The code looks like this

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly object _syncRoot = new object();

    public MyClass(string parameter)
    {
        lock (_syncRoot)
        {
            // some code
        }
    }
}
```

I think lock is useless here because this code cannot be called in different threads. Every thread will create its own object instance calling constructor. But maybe I'm wrong and don't know something. Thanks.

**Edit:**
In the first answer of this question [C# Am i using lock correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721212/c-sharp-am-i-using-lock-correctly) I found

> It's best to put a lock around the code within the constructor, as I
>   believe it's possible in certain circumstances that methods can be
>   called before the constructor block has finished executing.

So, it could be an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Am i using lock correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721212/c-sharp-am-i-using-lock-correctly)

Comment: The lock seems useless indeed, the only way such a lock would make some sense is when the `_syncRoot` is static

Comment: There is an explanation why it is could be useful in mentioned by @Sinatr question.

Comment: @Sinatr thanks, it looks like not a dublicate - different questions, but there in the first answer an interesting thing exists `It's best to put a lock around the code within the constructor, as I believe it's possible in certain circumstances that methods can be called before the constructor block has finished executing. (Someone please correct me if I'm wrong on this one.)`. So, it could be an answer. Thanks

Comment: It would be nice to see what "some code" is exactly. It's hard to *imagine* scenario, but if there is one we can tell you if `lock` is required.

Comment: Nothing special in fact, fields initialization.

Comment: Is the `lock(this) { ... }` block inside constructor also useless?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are absolutely right, `lock` is completely useless, because it is locking on an instance variable, while no outside caller could access it anyway.

I would imagine that this code would become useful if `_syncRoot` were declared `static`, in which case the semantic of critical section protected by the lock would change from one-per-instance to one-per-class.

**Edit:** (in response to a comment by Sinatr) The above makes an assumption about the code inside the critical section, that it makes no method calls that use `_syncRoot` object for locking as well. If there are such methods calls, their critical sections would be granted access, because the thread already holds the monitor.

Comment: *"no outside caller could access it"* - what if it's used to synchronize access inside the class? E.g. constructor *slowly* creates threads (passing them `this`) and `lock` is used to ensure none of them will access some member before initialization is finished?

Comment: @Sinatr Thanks for a useful comment!

Comment: ha, I doubt the instance not even yet exist (uninitialized?) unless the constructor completed successfully.

Comment: that is a good question.. especially when using DI... Can another thread call this object before the construct finishes?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, if it's not a static field, it's almost certainly useless.

It *could* be used to force a memory barrier if there's anything within the lock that requires it. More likely though it's either over-use (won't have any effect) or under-use (there should be a lock, but it should be on a static field).

Outside of the memory-barrier case, the most justifiable reason for this is that there was a rule of "always deal with these fields in a lock" that makes sense in other members, and the coder didn't realise this was an exception.

Comment: If they wanted a memory barrier, they could lock on a local instance, i.e. `var syncRoot = new object(); lock (syncRoot) { ... }`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes, though if the field was also used locks elsewhere then it might as well be used there, too. Without seeing more code I'd bet on it being a mistake rather than for good reason.